# Rewrite rule for permalink on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks, rules

I am working on a wordpress site that is running in a subdomain.
I have added the subfolder on WP .htaccess file to let all the site and permalinks work, so my WP site is running under

> http://example.com/subfolder/

Now I need to do the following:

I have this permalink structure that goes to a post:

> example.com/subfolder/the-post-permalink

And I need to add a rule that send this URL:

> example.com/subfolder/the-post-permalink-**category**

to:

> example.com/subfolder/the-post-permalink?param=**category**

So the post page displayed will be the same, but I will get a GET parameter with "param" value that was sent in the rewrite rule.

I have tried this with the add_rewrite_rule() method on the functions.php file, but could not make it work. Tried adding or not the subdolfer in the rule.

```
add_action('init', 'add_htaccess_redirects' ,10, 0);
function add_htaccess_redirects()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^subfolder/the-post-permalink-(.*)',
        'subfolder/the-post-permalink?param=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

and

```
add_action('init', 'add_htaccess_redirects' ,10, 0);
function add_htaccess_redirects()
{
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '^the-post-permalink-(.*)',
        'the-post-permalink?param=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Any help please?
Thanks.